# Asking question about upgrades and versions of software, would this be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have spent the last hour or so going over questions on the site and here on meta. I am pretty sure if I was to ask the question on Stack Overflow or Code Review it would get closed as off topic or too broad. For this site I am not so sure. It seems kind of grey.

The question I would like to ask at Software Recommendations is about MS Entity Framework Core vs Entity Framework 6. Specifically I want to ask something like "Going forward would it be better to just start using EF Core, even with windows WPF desktop applications?" which is essentially soliciting "why" and "why not" dialog which could easily be too broad and opinionated.

So what I am asking here is this kind of question right for this site?

Comment: "A vs B" is off-topic here (see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)).

Comment: "Going forward would it be better to just start using EF core, even with windows WPF desktop applications?" The thing is, it strongly depends on what you want to do with it. If you specify exactly what you want to achieve and kind of limit the available tools to these two, then it might be on topic. Not sure though. But you have to specify your specific requirements at the very least.